# Can't blit image in for loop more than once

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to `blit` the value of `"wPawn"` 8 times on the screen moving the x value by 60 each time so it is placed across the whole screen but it will only work once.

```py
import pygame as pg
import time

def menu():
  pass

pg.init()
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
size = [480,480]
display = pg.display.set_mode(size)
display.fill("WHITE")

board = pg.image.load("Chess\ChessBoard810.png").convert_alpha()
display.blit(board, (0, 0))#480x480

pieces = dict.fromkeys(["wPawn", "wRook", "wKnight", "wBishop", "wQueen", "wKing",
          "bPawn", "bRook", "bKnight", "bBishop", "bQueen", "bKing"])
for i in pieces:
  piece = pg.image.load(f"Chess\{i}.png")
  pieces[i] = piece

for i in range(8):
  xPos = 2.5
  yPos = 360
  display.blit(pieces.get("wPawn"), (xPos, yPos))
  pg.display.flip()
  print("Blit")
  xPos += 60

display.blit(pieces.get("wPawn"), (2.5+60, 360))

while True:
  pg.display.update()
pg.quit()
```

I'm trying Pygame for the first time and am trying to `blit` multiple images in a for loop with the position of the image incrementing to have 8 across the screen, but when I run the program the image is only `blit` once.

Comment: `xPos = 2.5` has to be set before the `for`-loop, but not in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
xPos = 2.5
yPos = 360

for i in range(8):
  display.blit(pieces.get("wPawn"), (xPos, yPos))
  print("Blit")
  xPos += 60

pg.display.flip()
display.blit(pieces.get("wPawn"), (2.5+60, 360))

while True:
   ....
```

and you should move the pg.display.flip() outside of the for loop and place it after the while True loop, so that the screen updates only once per frame